# Adobe Photoshop — How do I set the arrow keys to always move objects by 1px, regardless of zoom?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transform, zoom

I want to be able to reliably move objects in Photoshop with the arrow keys by 1px, regardless of zoom. When the document is not at scale, the arrow keys randomly move objects by either 2px or 3px (alternating between them whilst zoom remains the same). Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, GreenPotato, Welcome to GDSE. We hope you enjoy your time here sharing knowledge and experience.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge you can't change the default nudging behavior.

What you can do is record 4 actions: for moving a layer in 4 directions and assign them to hotkeys.

However another problem is that it's impossible to reassign some hotkeys in Photoshop, including the arrow keys, so you won't be able to assign the actions to arrow keys. A solution to this would be using a 3rd party remapping tool (like [AHK](https://www.autohotkey.com/) on Windows or [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) on Mac) to remap keys, for example remapping Win+Arrows to whatever F-keys that are used for move actions.